# Is it possible to initialize a View from different Layout?

Tags: android

I have an `Activity` and associated with it `layout`. Also I have another `layout` with some `Views`. I want to initialize a variable (`TextView`) from my `Activity` using a `View` from that standalone `layout`. I always get `null`.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button); // This is OK 
// because R.id.button is from R.layout.main layout

        tvOne = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.first_item); // This is not OK
// because R.id.first_item is from another layout.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct behaviour, because `findViewById()` will only search for views set in the view hierarchy passed to `setContentView()`

Comment: Let it be the correct behavior but can it be possible in general?

Comment: you can call setContentView() only once per activity, so no.

Comment: I think you could use a LayoutInflator to do it but I have no example because I don't recall ever seeing it done this way. Out of curiousity what are you going to do with the TextView once you get a reference to it? There may be a different way to get done whatever your needing.

Answer (score 3):

You can't instantiate a view within another layout, but you can instantiate a layout which can be the view you want.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
TextView text = (TextView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.contenttext, yourRootView, false);
```

Here would be the corresponding layout (contenttext.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:textSize="12sp"/>
```